# how to replace url of webpage with ip adress

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

i am trying to basically replace a webpage's url with its ip address for example, instead of

```
www.facebook.com
```

i want to replace it with

```
66.220.153.11
```

**Rationale**
i have recently discovered that our school blocks websites based on a particular string patern in the url for example www.**facebook.com** is blocked but **66.220.153.11** is not yet they are the same thing.

so i want to learn how to do this using javascript(is this possible?) so i can develop a firefox addon to automatically change the url **www.facebook.com** to **66.220.153.11** and beat the censorship.
i am usually a c programmer but i know little javascript. Help me out. Thanks

Comment: +1 Interesting question, but `yet they are the same thing.` is incorrect: Only if the site is configured to show the site when entering the IP this will work. For the vast majority of sites, it won't.

Comment: @pekka: **For the vast majority of sites, it won't** . Give us an illustrative example of a website where replacing the url with ip address wont work. Thanks

Comment: I have one for you: Facebook :) Try to log in from the page you opened using the IP. Apart from that, every web site that runs on shared hosting is bound not to work (because multiple domains share one IP). However, all major sites do work, as a cursory check shows

Comment: There are good security reasons why websites should not allow access to a browser that fails to supply the correct `Host:` header. See DNS rebinding and cross-subdomain cookie attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Assuming accessing the site via the IP works*)

I don't know in how detailed you expect an answer to be, but here is a general approach:

- **Changing the host**
  This is easy. The [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Location_object) object has an attribute `hostname`. If you have the IP address, you can just assign it to `location.hostname`. On change, the site will reload ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/HhpSC/) - of course the target page does not exist).
  In your plugin, you can attach an event handler for the `load` event to the `gBrowser` object. Read about [*Intercepting Page Loads*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads).
- **Getting the IP address**
  This is trickier. The only thing that comes to my mind is to use some web service
  that does host name to IP resolution. So you would have to use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) with (probably) [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) for this.

I hope this gives you a start.

Answer (score 1):

This cant't work for the most domains in the world, because the IP points to a server, not to a domain.
If there are hosted different domains on the same server(often hundreds of domains are hosted on one server), there is no way to point at the wanted domain without knowledge of the virtualhost-settings(which are usually not public).

You may take a look at this and see, how many domains can depend on a single IP:
http://www.robtex.com/ip/194.117.254.46.html

Also see, how many domains are hosted on the facebook-IP:
http://www.robtex.com/ip/66.220.153.11.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a proxy to bypass the blocks?